# Did I construct my integral correctly? - Find the surface area of the cone $z = \sqrt{x^2 +y^2}$ bounded in the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 4x$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, area

In a practice test, there's a question that wants us to find the surface area of a cone  $z = \sqrt{x^2 +y^2}$ that's bounded by $x^2 + y^2 = 4x$. 
I'm really shaky on the subject matter and since there are no answers I'd love to get a feedback on the integral:

 **my thoughts and attempts**:
I've concluded I need to use a type one surface integral where $f=1:$ $$\iint_S ds$$ There's a given shortcut where $z$ is explicit but I've opted not to use it because I thought it'd lead to a harder integral.
Using both of the equations I defined $R = (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta, r)$ where $\frac{-\pi}{2} \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2} ~$ and $~0 \leq r \leq 4 \cos \theta$. 
 I calculated $|R_r \times R_\theta| = \sqrt{2} \cdot r$, and so I've transformed it into a double integral -
$$ \displaystyle \iint_S ds = \sqrt2 \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{4 \cos\theta} r ~  dr ~d\theta $$
is this correct? are there better ways of doing this?

Comment: Yes it looks correct.

Comment: the thing that bugs me with it is that theta should be between 0 and 2pi, but if defined in this way then -0.5pi should be 3/2 pi and this messes up the sign of the final result.

Comment: No, $\theta$ doesn't have to be between $0 $ and $2 \pi$.  What you did is correct.  Otherwise you could change the limits to $[ \dfrac{3\pi}{2} , \dfrac{5 \pi}{2} ]$